# Как переименовать ключи в объекте

Tags: javascript

У меня есть массив. Его необходимо преобразовать в объект и сделать имя ключа идентичное его значению. То есть: [4, 6, 9, 'hello'] --- {4: 4, 6: 6, 9: 9, hello : "hello"}. У меня получилось преобразовать его в объект, но не понимаю как изменить имя ключа.

```
let a10 = [4, 6, 9, 'Hello'];

function f10() {
    let a10Clone = Object.assign({}, a10)
    for(let key in a10Clone){
        key = a10Clone[key]
    }
    return a10Clone
}

document.querySelector('.b-10').addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(f10());
});
```

Comment: в примере `'Hello'` не идентично `hello : "hello"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во время преобразования по сути все равно создаётся другой объект. Поэтому нет смысла в прямом смысле вот прям "преобразовать". Создаем новый объект и заполняем его так, как требуется.

```js
let a10 = [4, 6, 9, 'Hello'];

function f10() {
    let a10Clone = {};
    a10.forEach(elem => {
      a10Clone[elem] = elem;
    });
    return a10Clone
}

document.querySelector('.b-10').addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(f10());
});
```

```html
<div class="b-10">Для примера</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Например воспользоваться функцией `reduce`

```js
let a10 = [4, 6, 9, 'Hello'];


const newArr = a10.reduce((res, item) => {
  res[item] = item;
  return res;
}, {})

console.log(newArr)
```